# How to order by Month starting from a selected Month in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with a Code and Description column. The Description column contains the months of the year in consecutive order, and the code is the month number (e.g. Code = 1, Description = January).

I want to write a SQL query which takes the previous month (from the current month) and returns a table starting from that month and sorting months in ascending order (the previous month is August, so the table will start with August on row 1 with a code of 8 and next is September, 9 etc.)

My code so far:

```
DECLARE @PreviousMonth INT = MONTH(DATEADD(mm, -1, GETDATE()))
SELECT @PreviousMonth
SELECT
     MonthNumber AS Code,
     MonthName AS Description
FROM
    MonthName
ORDER BY MONTH(DATEADD(mm, -1, GETDATE()))
```

So if the current month is September, August will be the previous month.

Expected result (Code on the left, description on the right):

```
8 August
9 September 
10 October
11 November
12 December
1 January
2 February
3 March
4 April
5 May
6 June
7 July
```

Comment: I think what you are describing is not *ordering* but *renumbering*.

Comment: I assume this is Microsoft SQL-Server?  You will need a where clause to get the starting month, something like     WHERE MonthNumber>= @previousMonth.    Also, why not simply order by MonthNumber?

Comment: Can you add your expected query result to your question.

Comment: Added expected query result

Comment: How much effort do you save writing `DATEADD(mm, ...` vs. `DATEADD(month, ...`? And how much more readable is the latter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ORDER BY
  MonthNumber + CASE WHEN MonthNumber < @PreviousMonth THEN 12 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you need to be able select a *range*, which will "loop around" to the start.

One way is to union your table of months to produce a list from 1-23:

```
    declare @PreviousMonth int = Month(DateAdd(mm, -1, GetDate()));

    with m as (
        select code, description 
        from t 
        union all
        select code+12, description 
        from t
    )
    select Iif(m.code>12, m.code % 12,code) code, m.description
    from m
    where m.code between @PreviousMonth and @PreviousMonth+11
    order by m.code
```

[Demo DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=80f32344824398c8b8c3b3c8beacc01d)